# Sometimes when I edit an agent, all of the code is gone, I have to re-open it later

Tags: domino-designer-eclipse

I am tired of just guessing at what to do in this situation.  Sometimes, when I go to edit an agent (not just agents, but mostly)....the agent opens, but all of the code is just missing.    If I come back later, it will be there again.  This has to be a problem with Eclipse, but I am wondering if everyone has this problem, and if there is a specific way to remedy this.

To be clear, this will happen to a mature agent that has a lot of script written in it over time, and I am wanting to make a change.

Thoughts or ideas?

Comment: Which version ?

Comment: IBM Domino Designer 9.0
Social Edition

Release 9.0.1 
Revision 20131022.0932 (Release 9.0.1) 
Standard Configuration
L-GHUS-968PRV

Comment: What about an update to FP9 ? Between 9.0.1 and FP 9 there had been a lot of improvement..

Comment: I can ask my admins about that, I have no control over it, and will see.   Thanks.